# Who wrote the Piskei Tosfos?

Tags: talmud-gemara, jewish-books, tosfot, authorship

After the section of Gemara in most sefarim, before the Rosh there is a section of the Piskei Tosfos. Who authored this work?

Comment: I remember seeing that Piskei Tosafos was not written based on our Tosafos, but a different version of Tosafos (there were many).  This would especially make sense if the author was the uncle of R' Eliezer of Touques, who wrote most of the Tosafos published in our Gemaras today. This is why the Piskei Tosafos often do not match our Tosafos.

Answer (score 6):

[Wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA)

Per Rabbi Yaakov Emden in his Sefer Mishna Lechem Pesachim Chapter 10 it was authored by Rabbi Yaakov ben Asher - the Tur. There are those who attribute it to the Tur's father - the Rosh. The Chida in ספר ברכי יוסף, אורח חיים סימן רצא סעיף קטן ז questions as to what the source is that it was written by either the Tur or the Rosh.

There are those that say it was authored by Rabbi Chezkiya or Rabbi Yechezkia the uncle of Rabbi Eliezer Matuch. Also mentioned as a possible author is  Rabbi Yaakov ben Rabbi Meir Katz from Nordhausen who was killed in 1349 due to the [black death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Death) and subsequent [black death Jewish persecutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Death_Jewish_persecutions).

Comment: Do you have a citation in the Shem HaGedolim for this? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for the addition.‎ Sorry to bother you again,‎ but do you have a source for who says the Piskei Tosofos are the names in the second paragraph? Thanks!

Comment: @ak0000 click on the wikipedia link,

Answer (score 0):

see chida shem hagidolim os peh who says some say it was the Rosh and some say it was the Tur